# Populate DropDownList from WebDataGrid

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, webdatagrid

I have a WebDataGrid linked to a SqlDataSource to display data.  When a row is selected, I want to populate some textboxes and dropdownlists with the data from that row, for editing purposes.  The textboxes work fine; I use the following code to select the second field in the grid (Date) and populate the corresponding textbox (I'm using VB):

```
txtDate.Text = currentRow.Items(2).Value
```

However, when I try to populate the dropdownlists using the same code structure, I get the following error:

```
'ddlType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
```

I think the problem may be that the dropdownlists are populated using type_id, while the grid displays type_name.  Would this be causing the problem, and is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things you could try:

1. Change the SQLDataSource to return the type_id also and set the column to visible="false" that way you could select that field instead of the name and use that for .SelectedValue.
2. If that is not possible then you could use code like this (this will only work if the text that is displayed in the drop down is unique and is exactly the same as what is displayed in the grid view):

   `'replace this with the call to currentRow.Items(#).Value`
     `Dim sometext As String = "type_name"`

   `DropDownListName.Items.FindByText(sometext).Selected = True`
3. The other possibility is to loop through each element in the drop down and find the text, this is like the brute force method but works.

   `'replace this with the call to currentRow.Items(#).Value`

   `Dim sometext As String = "type_name"`

   `For Each ddItem As ListItem In ddArriveAMPM.Items`

   ```
    `If String.Compare(sometext, ddItem.Text, True) = 1 Then`   
        `ddItem.Selected = True`
     `End If`        
   `Next`
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second option (I'm pretty new to ASP.NET).  How can I get the type_name of the selected row without using currentRow.Items(#).Value?  (Each item in the dropdownlist is unique and it is the same as the name displayed in the grid view.)

Comment: Thanks - I'm using the first suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the item to the listbox before you can select it.

```
DropDownListX.Items.Add("Item");
```

or

```
DropDownListX.Items.Add(new ListItem("String","Value"));
```

Make sure to clear the DropDown box when selecting a new row otherwise the old rows values will stay in there.

```
DropDownListX.Items.Clear();
```

After this you can use SelectedValue

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error message:   "Invalid postback or callback argument...For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."   And populating the textboxes also stopped working.

Comment: By the way, for: DropDownListX.Items.Add(new ListItem("String","Value")); -- would the parameters be currentRow.Items(1).Value (or whichever field number I need)?

Comment: Yes, maybe good to do a currentRow.Items(1).Value.ToString(). You can do it for both of the items so you can use SelectedValue later in code if you dont have an id or something to bind the the value